# strtotime with datetimepicker

Tags: php, jquery, date, strtotime

I'm using the datetimepicker jquery plugin and have the following code to display it:

```
var dateToday = new Date();
$('#post_date_picker').datetimepicker({
    minDate: dateToday,
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm p z',
    timezoneList: [ 
        { value: -300, label: 'Eastern'}, 
        { value: -360, label: 'Central' }, 
        { value: -420, label: 'Mountain' }, 
        { value: -480, label: 'Pacific' } 
    ]
});
```

Since I'm displaying it in 12 hour format instead of 24 and using the min date if the server time is already PM I can select the time and it outputs it like `05/27/2015 08:50 p -0500`

I then do the following code to get the date ready to be inserted into the database:

```
$date_time = strtotime($_POST['post_date']);
$post_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date_time);
```

The problem is strtotime isn't recongining the `p` for PM and is inserting the date basically 12 hours previously. How can I do this?

Comment: Try changnign the `p` to `A`. I suspect that will make the value valid for PHP

Comment: @JohnConde I tried this but got the same result.

Comment: Try getting rid of the z as it is not needed code.

Answer (score 0):

Set **timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt z'**.

And in php use **date_create & date_format ( $date_time,'Y-m-d h:i:sA')**

See the difference between( strtotime / date_create ).

```
// method using date_create

//$date=$_POST['post_date'];

$date='05/27/2015 08:50 p -0500';

$date_time=date_create($date);

$post_date=date_format($date_time,'Y-m-d H:i:s'); 

echo $post_date."<br>";//outputs 2015-05-27 08:50:00


//method using strtotime

$date_time = strtotime($date);

$post_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date_time);

echo $post_date;//outputs 2015-05-27 13:50:00
```

strtotime can take many string parameters, may be when you pass the date as '05/27/2015 08:50 p -0500' some conflict is occurring resulting in wrong interpretation of time.